# What port is this *picture* (mid 2007 13 inch macbook)?

Tags: mac, hardware, display, accessories, vga-adapter

I've been trying to hookup this MacBook I have to an external monitor, but I don't know which adapter to buy. I bought a VGA adapter on eBay, but the connector is really thin. Can someone direct me to what port this is, and bonus points if you can find me an ebay listing.

I've looked up the model on Apple but they don't give me specifics on the item.
It's a mid-2007 13" MacBook.

[image: mid 2007 13 inch macbook left side ports]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This pictured connector on your mid 2007 13 inch MacBook is a **mini DVI connector** according to http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3235

[image: Mini DVI port illustration][image: Apple M9320G photo]

The Apple part number for the **Apple Mini-DVI to VGA Adapter** is: **M9320G**.

And the eBay link: http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=M9320G

Comment: Thanks, your experience has saved me time and money. Appreciate it.